# What does a negative wetting tension $\delta F$ mean?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, physical-chemistry, surface-tension, wetting

If a solid polymer has a drop of liquid (water) and shows a negative value of wetting tension, what does this mean? Does this mean that the drop of liquid will bead up instead of spreading on the solid surface?

I am trying to understand the wetting dynamics of a polymer's surface, wetted with water. Wetting tension (delta F), being one of the wetting parameters shows a negative value and does increase to a positive value after certain surface treatment. But in pristine form, it shows a negative value of wetting tension.

Comment: Assuming you mean the [ASTM definition for *wetting tension*](https://www.astm.org/d2578-17.html) it cannot be negative.

Answer (score 0):

"Wetting tension" is a term I am not familiar with. The common way to describe the wettability of one substance by a liquid (say, water) is to measure its *contact angle*. If the contact angle is greater than 90 degrees, the liquid tends to "ball up" on the surface and we say the surface is *poorly wetted* by the liquid. If less than 90 degrees, the droplet tends to spread out into a flattish shape and we say the solid is *well-wetted*. If the contact angle is 90 degrees, the droplet of fluid will form itself into a hemisphere.

Many polymers are poorly wetted by water until they have been treated by an *oxygen plasma* which creates a near-monolayer of "plastic oxide" on the surface. The oxygens that populate the surface resemble the oxygens in a water molecule, and it is therefore easy for water to wet out and get friendly with an oxygenated surface.